# Increase the number after clicking Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem that I can't solve, I'm on an application where you have to vote for the most beautiful cat.

The problem is that the images are displayed randomly and I can't increase the number of votes after clicking. I've tried browsing Stack Overflow several times without success.

In my `voteForThisCat()` method, I'm trying things without success

**html**

```
<div class="cat" *ngFor="let cat of twoCatsArray" (click)="voteForThisCat(cat.id)">
    <img class="cat-image" [src]="cat.url">
</div>
```

**ts.file**

```
twoCatsArray: Cat[] = [];
allcats: Cat[];
ratingArray: Cat[] = [];

constructor(private catService: CatService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.showMeTwoCats();
}

showMeTwoCats() {
  this.catService.getAllCat().subscribe((cats: CatList) => {
    this.allcats = cats.images;
    this.twoCatsArray = this.chooseTwoRandomCats(this.allcats);
  });
}

chooseTwoRandomCats(cats: Cat[]): Cat[] {
  const firstCatIndex = this.getRandomIndex(cats.length);
  const secondCatIndex = this.getRandomIndex(cats.length, firstCatIndex);

  return [cats[firstCatIndex], cats[secondCatIndex]];
}

getRandomIndex(maxValue: number, differentThanValue?: number): number {
  let index: number;
  do {
   index = this.getRandomInt(maxValue);
 }  while (index === differentThanValue);

 return index;
}

getRandomInt(max: number): number {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

voteForThisCat(id: string) {
  const likedCatindex = this.allcats.findIndex((cat: Cat) => cat.id === id);
  this.twoCatsArray = this.chooseTwoRandomCats(this.allcats);
}

getIncrementedCatRatingValue(rating: number): number {
  return rating ? ++rating : 1;
}
```

**json**

```
{
  "images": [
    {
        "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m82woaL5AD1rro1o5o1_1280.jpg",
        "id": "MTgwODA3MA"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m29a9d62C81r2rj8po1_500.jpg",
        "id": "tt"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m4bgd9OXmw1qioo2oo1_500.jpg",
        "id": "bmp"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lzxok2e2kX1qgjltdo1_1280.jpg",
        "id": "c8a"
    },
 ]
}
```

**interface**

```
export interface Cat {
  url: string;
  id: string;
  rating: number;
}

export interface CatList {
  images: Cat[];
}
```

Comment: In `voteForThisCat`, just use `find` to get the `Cat` and increment its `rating` (assuming it has one; hard to answer without knowing how `Cat` is defined...

Comment: Why do you call `chooseTwoRandomCats` in `voteForThisCat`?

Comment: @Konrad to display different cat images after each click

Comment: `getIncrementedCatRatingValue` is never called (at least in the above code snippet).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I updated my code with my interface

Comment: @PrerakSola `getIncrementedCatRatingValue()` is never called because I don't know what to pass it as data

Comment: You can do something like `this.allcats[likedCatindex].rating = getIncrementedCatRatingValue(this.allcats[likedCatindex].rating)` after getting the index.

Comment: @PrerakSola  how can i access the information where the ratings are so that i can consol.log() with your code? because it doesn't seem to work at the moment because it increments 1 several times.

Comment: So yeah, just do `const likedCat = this.allcats.find((cat: Cat) => cat.id === id); likedCat.rating = (likedCat.rating ?? 0) + 1;`

Comment: You can do `console.log(this.allcats[likedCatindex])` to see the clicked object.

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework assignment.  You provided enough code to show exactly what needs to happen.  I recommend you also show what you've tried that didn't work so that we can guide you in your thought process, rather than just providing you with the answer.